# Alternatives for PHP older version functions

Tags: php, function, system-paths

Anyone knows alternative function for `sys_get_temp_dir` and `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` and `tempnam` in PHP

existing PHP version is 4.*

Comment: Just... what? Why?

Comment: We have older version of PHP on our server so I cant find an alternative for reading system temp directory path

Comment: If you need a compat layer for `tempnam` does that mean you're running php3?

Comment: sys_get_temp_dir exists in php 7

Comment: I think the issue in that case is that you're using a version of PHP that hasn't been developed, secured or supported in any way for 8+ years...

Comment: Which version of PHP 4.*? Do you mean 4.3? Please edit this into your question.

Comment: As stop-gap measure for outdated setups consider the [upgradephp](https://github.com/Polycademy/upgradephp) shim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tempnam exists in PHP4

[You can use this code from php.net to get a temp dir:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php#93390)

```
if ( !function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) { 
  function sys_get_temp_dir() { 
    if (!empty($_ENV['TMP'])) { return realpath($_ENV['TMP']); } 
    if (!empty($_ENV['TMPDIR'])) { return realpath( $_ENV['TMPDIR']); } 
    if (!empty($_ENV['TEMP'])) { return realpath( $_ENV['TEMP']); } 
    $tempfile=tempnam(__FILE__,''); 
    if (file_exists($tempfile)) { 
      unlink($tempfile); 
      return realpath(dirname($tempfile)); 
    } 
    return null; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys...! Its working on our server even if its -32 vote on http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php#93390

Comment: I dont know Why people voted -ve

Comment: Updated this question as answer!

Comment: some of people think it is not a unique question and is related with other question so they give negative voting. But they don't know the exact reason for the user or not ask the reason for asking the question from the posting user.